# unrecognized selector sent to instance in xcode using objective c and sup as backend

Tags: objective-c, xcode, sup

I am a beginner in native development.I made a project using xcode in objective C.It builded successfully.But when I run the project ,an error came like 
'unrecognized selector sent to instance'.Why this is happening ?can anyone help me to solve this?I am attaching the error that I am getting with this..

[image]
And I am posting the code with this....

ConnectionController.m

```
#import "ConnectionController.h"
#import "SUPApplication.h"
#import "Flight_DetailsFlightDB.h"
#import "CallbackHandler.h"


@interface ConnectionController()

@property (nonatomic,retain)CallbackHandler *callbackhandler;

@end


@implementation ConnectionController


@synthesize callbackhandler;

static ConnectionController *appConnectionController;

//Begin Application Setup



+(void)beginApplicationSetup
{

    if(!appConnectionController)
    {

        appConnectionController = [[[ConnectionController alloc]init]retain];
        appConnectionController.callbackhandler = [[CallbackHandler getInstance]retain];


    }
    if([SUPApplication connectionStatus] == SUPConnectionStatus_DISCONNECTED)


        [appConnectionController setupApplicationConnection];

    else 

        NSLog(@"Already Connected");

}


-(BOOL)setupApplicationConnection
{

    SUPApplication *app = [SUPApplication getInstance];

    [app setApplicationIdentifier:@"HWC"];
    [app setApplicationCallback:self.callbackhandler];
    NSLog(@"inside setupApp");
    SUPConnectionProperties *properties = [app connectionProperties];
    NSLog(@"server");
    [properties setServerName:@"sapecxxx.xxx.com"];
    NSLog(@"inside setupAppser");    
    [properties setPortNumber:5001];
    NSLog(@"inside setupApppot");   
    [properties setFarmId:@"0"];
    NSLog(@"inside setupAppfarm");    
    [properties setUrlSuffix:@"/tm/?cid=%cid%"];
    NSLog(@"inside setupAppurlsuff"); 
    [properties setNetworkProtocol:@"http"];

    SUPLoginCredentials *loginCred = [SUPLoginCredentials getInstance];
    NSLog(@"inside setupAppmac");    
    [loginCred setUsername:@"mac"];
    [loginCred setPassword:nil];
    [properties setLoginCredentials:loginCred];
    [properties setActivationCode:@"1234"];


    if(![Flight_DetailsFlightDB databaseExists])
    {

        [Flight_DetailsFlightDB createDatabase];

    }

    SUPConnectionProfile *connprofile = [Flight_DetailsFlightDB getSynchronizationProfile];
   [connprofile setNetworkProtocol:@"http"];
    NSLog(@"inside setupAppPort2");   
    [connprofile setPortNumber:2480];
    NSLog(@"inside setupAppser2");    
   [connprofile setServerName:@"sapecxxx.xxx.com"]; 
    NSLog(@"inside setupAppdom2");    
    [connprofile setDomainName:@"Development"];
    NSLog(@"inside setupAppuser");    
    [connprofile setUser:@"supAdmin"];
    [connprofile setPassword:@"s3pAdmin"];
    [connprofile setAsyncReplay:YES];
    [connprofile setClientId:@"0"];
  //  [Flight_DetailsFlightDB beginOnlineLogin:@"supAdmin" password:@"s3pAdmin"];

    [Flight_DetailsFlightDB registerCallbackHandler:self.callbackhandler];
    [Flight_DetailsFlightDB setApplication:app];


    if([SUPApplication connectionStatus] == SUPRegistrationStatus_REGISTERED)
    {

        [app startConnection:0];

    }
    else 
    {
        [app registerApplication:0];
    }


}

@end
```

ViewController.m

```
#import "Demo_FlightsViewController.h"
#import "ConnectionController.h"
#import "Flight_DetailsFlightDB.h"
#import "SUPObjectList.h"
#import "Flight_DetailsSessionPersonalization.h"
#import "Flight_DetailsFlight_MBO.h"
#import "Flight_DetailsPersonalizationParameters.h"


@interface Demo_FlightsViewController ()

@end

@implementation Demo_FlightsViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}
-(IBAction)Connect:(id)sender
{
    @try
    {
        [ConnectionController beginApplicationSetup];

    }
    @catch (NSException *exception) 
    {

        NSLog(@"ConnectionAborted");

    }

    // synchronise
}

-(IBAction)Synchronise:(id)sender
{
    @try 
    {
        [Flight_DetailsFlightDB synchronize];
        NSLog(@"SYNCHRONISED");
    }
    @catch (NSException *exception) 
    {

        NSLog(@"Synchronisation Failed");

    }

}

-(IBAction)findall:(id)sender
{


    SUPObjectList *list = [Flight_DetailsSessionPersonalization findAll];

    NSLog(@"no of lines got synchronised is %d",list.size);

}

-(IBAction)confirm:(id)sender
{


    Flight_DetailsPersonalizationParameters *pp = [Flight_DetailsFlightDB getPersonalizationParameters];
    MBOLogInfo(@"personalisation parmeter for  airline id= %@",pp.Airline_PK);
    [pp setAirline_PK:@"AA"];
    [pp save];

    while([Flight_DetailsFlightDB hasPendingOperations])
    {
        [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:1];

    }
    NSLog(@"inside confirm............");
    [Flight_DetailsFlightDB beginSynchronize];

    Flight_DetailsFlight_MBO *flight = nil;
    SUPObjectList *cl = nil;
    cl =[Flight_DetailsFlight_MBO findAll]; 


    if(cl && cl.length > 0)
    {
        int i;
        for(i=0;i<cl.length;i++)
        {
            flight = [cl item:i];
             if(flight)
             {
                 NSLog(@"details are %@",flight.CITYFROM);
             }
        }
    }


}



- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown);
}

@end
```

SUPConnectionProfile.h

```
#import "sybase_sup.h"
#define FROM_IMPORT_THREAD   TRUE
#define FROM_APP_THREAD      FALSE
#define SUP_UL_MAX_CACHE_SIZE 10485760

@class SUPBooleanUtil;
@class SUPNumberUtil;
@class SUPStringList;
@class SUPStringUtil;
@class SUPPersistenceException;
@class SUPLoginCertificate;
@class SUPLoginCredentials;
@class SUPConnectionProfile;

/*!
 @class SUPConnectionProfile
 @abstract   This class contains fields and methods needed to connect and authenticate to an SUP server.
 @discussion 
 */
@interface SUPConnectionProfile : NSObject
{
    SUPConnectionProfile* _syncProfile;
    SUPBoolean _threadLocal;
    SUPString _wrapperData;    
    NSMutableDictionary* _delegate;
    SUPLoginCertificate* _certificate;
    SUPLoginCredentials* _credentials;
    int32_t _maxDbConnections;
    BOOL      initTraceCalled;
}

/*!
    @method     
    @abstract   Return a new instance of SUPConnectionProfile.
    @discussion 
    @result The SUPconnectionprofile object.
*/

+ (SUPConnectionProfile*)getInstance;

/*!
 @method     
 @abstract   Return a new instance of SUPConnectionProfile.
 @discussion This method is deprecated. use getInstance instead.
 @result The SUPconnectionprofile object.
 */

+ (SUPConnectionProfile*)newInstance DEPRECATED_ATTRIBUTE NS_RETURNS_NON_RETAINED;
- (SUPConnectionProfile*)init;

/*!
 @property     
 @abstract   The sync profile.
 @discussion 
 */
@property(readwrite, retain, nonatomic) SUPConnectionProfile* syncProfile;

/*!
 @property
 @abstract The maximum number of active DB connections allowed
 @discussion Default value is 4, but can be changed by application developer.
 */
@property(readwrite, assign, nonatomic) int32_t maxDbConnections;

/*!
    @method     
    @abstract   The SUPConnectionProfile manages an internal dictionary of key value pairs. This method returns the SUPString value for a given string.
    @discussion 
    @param name The string.
*/
- (SUPString)getString:(SUPString)name;

/*!
 @method     
 @abstract   The SUPConnectionProfile manages an internal dictionary of key value pairs. This method returns the SUPString value for a given string.
 If the value is not found, returns 'defaultValue'.
 @discussion 
 @param name The string.
 @param defaultValue The default Value.
 */
- (SUPString)getStringWithDefault:(SUPString)name:(SUPString)defaultValue;

/*!
 @method     
 @abstract   The SUPConnectionProfile manages an internal dictionary of key value pairs. This method returns the SUPBoolean value for a given string.
 @discussion 
 @param name The string.
 */
- (SUPBoolean)getBoolean:(SUPString)name;

/*!
 @method     
 @abstract   The SUPConnectionProfile manages an internal dictionary of key value pairs. This method returns the SUPBoolean value for a given string.
 If the value is not found, returns 'defaultValue'.
 @discussion 
 @param name The string.
 @param defaultValue The default Value.
 */
- (SUPBoolean)getBooleanWithDefault:(SUPString)name:(SUPBoolean)defaultValue;

/*!
 @method     
 @abstract   The SUPConnectionProfile manages an internal dictionary of key value pairs. This method returns the SUPInt value for a given string.
 @discussion 
 @param name The string.
 */
- (SUPInt)getInt:(SUPString)name;


/*!
 @method     
 @abstract   The SUPConnectionProfile manages an internal dictionary of key value pairs. This method returns the SUPInt value for a given string.
 If the value is not found, returns 'defaultValue'.
 @discussion 
 @param name The string.
 @param defaultValue The default Value.
 */
- (SUPInt)getIntWithDefault:(SUPString)name:(SUPInt)defaultValue;
/*!
    @method   getUPA
    @abstract   retrieve upa from profile
    @discussion if it is in profile's dictionary, it returns value for key "upa";
                if it is not found in profile, it composes the upa value from base64 encoding of username:password;
                and also inserts it into profile's dictionary.
    @param      none
    @result     return string value of upa.
*/

- (SUPString)getUPA;

/*!
    @method     
    @abstract   Sets the SUPString 'value' for the given 'name'.
    @discussion 
    @param name The name.
    @param value The value.
*/
- (void)setString:(SUPString)name:(SUPString)value;

/*!
 @method     
 @abstract   Sets the SUPBoolean 'value' for the given 'name'.
 @discussion 
 @param name The name.
 @param value The value.
 */
- (void)setBoolean:(SUPString)name:(SUPBoolean)value;

/*!
 @method     
 @abstract   Sets the SUPInt 'value' for the given 'name'.
 @discussion 
 @param name The name.
 @param value The value.
 */
- (void)setInt:(SUPString)name:(SUPInt)value;

/*!
    @method     
    @abstract   Sets the username.
    @discussion 
    @param value The value.
*/
- (void)setUser:(SUPString)value;

/*!
 @method     
 @abstract   Sets the password.
 @discussion 
 @param value The value.
 */
- (void)setPassword:(SUPString)value;

/*!
 @method     
 @abstract   Sets the ClientId.
 @discussion 
 @param value The value.
 */
- (void)setClientId:(SUPString)value;

/*!
 @method     
 @abstract   Returns the databasename.
 @discussion 
 @param value The value.
 */
- (SUPString)databaseName;

/*!
 @method     
 @abstract   Sets the databasename.
 @discussion 
 @param value The value.
 */
- (void)setDatabaseName:(SUPString)value;
@property(readwrite,copy, nonatomic) SUPString databaseName;

/*!
 @method     
 @abstract   Gets the encryption key.
 @discussion 
 @result The encryption key.
 */
- (SUPString)getEncryptionKey;

/*!
 @method     
 @abstract   Sets the encryption key.
 @discussion 
 @param value The value.
 */
- (void)setEncryptionKey:(SUPString)value;

@property(readwrite,copy, nonatomic) SUPString encryptionKey;


/*!
 @property
 @abstract The authentication credentials (username/password or certificate) for this profile.
 @discussion
 */
@property(retain,readwrite,nonatomic) SUPLoginCredentials *credentials;
/*!
 @property     
 @abstract   The authentication certificate.
 @discussion If this is not null, certificate will be used for authentication.  If this is null, credentials property (username/password) will be used.
 */
@property(readwrite,retain,nonatomic) SUPLoginCertificate *certificate;
@property(readwrite, assign, nonatomic) BOOL initTraceCalled;

/*!
 @method     
 @abstract   Gets the UltraLite collation creation parameter
 @discussion 
 @result conllation string
 */
- (SUPString)getCollation;

/*!
 @method     
 @abstract   Sets the UltraLite collation creation parameter
 @discussion 
 @param value The value.
 */
- (void)setCollation:(SUPString)value;

@property(readwrite,copy, nonatomic) SUPString collation;

/*!
 @method     
 @abstract   Gets the maximum cache size in bytes; the default value for iOS is 10485760 (10 MB).
 @discussion 
 @result max cache size
 */
- (int)getCacheSize;
/*!
 @method     
 @abstract   Sets the maximum cache size in bytes.
 @discussion For Ultralite, passes the cache_max_size property into the connection parameters for DB connections; For SQLite, executes the "PRAGMA cache_size" statement when a connection is opened.
 @param cacheSize value
 */
- (void)setCacheSize:(int)cacheSize;

@property(readwrite,assign, nonatomic) int cacheSize;
/*!
    @method     
    @abstract   Returns the user.
    @discussion 
    @result The username.
*/
- (SUPString)getUser;
/*!
 @method     
 @abstract   Returns the password hash value.
 @discussion 
 @result The password hash value.
 */

- (NSUInteger)getPasswordHash;
/*!
 @method     
 @abstract   Returns the password.
 @discussion 
 @result The password hash value.
 */

- (NSString*)getPassword;

/*!
 @method     
 @abstract   Adds a new key value pair.
 @discussion 
 @param key The key.
 @param value The value.
 */
- (void)add:(SUPString)key:(SUPString)value;

/*!
    @method     
    @abstract   Removes the key.
    @discussion 
    @param key The key to remove.
*/

- (void)remove:(SUPString)key;
- (void)clear;

/*!
 @method     
 @abstract   Returns a boolean indicating if the key is present.
 @discussion 
 @param key The key.
 @result The result indicating if the key is present.
 */
- (SUPBoolean)containsKey:(SUPString)key;

/*!
 @method     
 @abstract   Returns the item for the given key.
 @discussion 
 @param key  The key.
 @result The item.
 */
- (SUPString)item:(SUPString)key;

/*!
 @method     
 @abstract   Returns the list of keys.
 @discussion 
 @result The keylist.
 */
- (SUPStringList*)keys;

/*!
 @method     
 @abstract   Returns the list of values.
 @discussion 
 @result The value list.
 */
- (SUPStringList*)values;

/*!
 @method     
 @abstract   Returns the internal map of key value pairs.
 @discussion 
 @result The NSMutableDictionary with key value pairs.
 */
- (NSMutableDictionary*)internalMap;
/*!
 @method     
 @abstract   Returns the domain name.
 @result The domain name.
 @discussion
*/
- (SUPString)getDomainName;

/*!
 @method     
 @abstract   Sets the domain name.
 @param value The domain name.
 @discussion 
 */
- (void)setDomainName:(SUPString)value;

/*!
 @method     
 @abstract   Get async operation replay property. Default is true.
 @result YES : if ansync operation replay is enabled; NO: if async operation is disabled.
 @discussion  
 */
- (BOOL) getAsyncReplay;

/*!
 @method     
 @abstract   Set async operation replay property. Default is true.
 @result value: enable/disable async replay operation.
 @discussion  
 */

- (void) setAsyncReplay:(BOOL) value;

/*!
 @method     
 @abstract   enable or disable the trace in client object API.
 @param enable - YES: enable the trace; NO: disable the trace.
 @discussion 
 */
- (void)enableTrace:(BOOL)enable;

/*!
 @method     
 @abstract   enable or disable the trace with payload info in client object API.
 @param enable - YES: enable the trace; NO: disable the trace.
 @param withPayload = YES: show payload information; NO: not show payload information.
 @discussion 
 */
- (void)enableTrace:(BOOL)enable withPayload:(BOOL)withPayload;

/*!
 @method     
 @abstract   initialize trace levels from server configuration.
 @discussion 
 */

- (void)initTrace;

- (void)dealloc;

/* ultralite/mobilink required parameters */
- (SUPString)getNetworkProtocol;
- (void)setNetworkProtocol:(SUPString)protocol;
- (SUPString)getNetworkStreamParams;
- (void)setNetworkStreamParams:(SUPString)stream;
- (SUPString)getServerName;
- (void)setServerName:(SUPString)name;
- (int)getPortNumber;
- (void)setPortNumber:(int)port;
- (int)getPageSize;
- (void)setPageSize:(int)size;

@end

@interface SUPConnectionProfile(internal)

- (void)applyPropertiesFromApplication;


@end
```

We are using SUP 2.1.3 library files.Please go through the code and help me...

Comment: Your calling a function in an object which does not exist. If you can post the code it will be easy to help you.

Comment: post your code. Its a very common error. It may be because of early release of instance.

Comment: @imthi and Abdullah Umer:Hey I have posted the code with this.Please check that

Answer (score 0):

There is an object of the class SUPConnectionProfile to which you are sening a selector (resp. calling a member function) named setNetworkProtocol with one ojbect as parameter. However there is no such method implemented - at least none with 1 object as parameter.

Comment: Well, if SUPConnectionProfile does not have a mehtod called setNetworkProtocol nor does it have a property called networkProtocol, why the h... are you calling it? If you think this is required then please share the .h and the related parts of the .m file with us.

Comment: What is SUPConnectionProfile? Some framework object? Do you have access to the .m file? If not then you could think of extending the existing class. But I have a guts feeling that you are not on the right route here.

Comment: Declaring a property or a method in the h file only may force the compiler to compile it but that could never run properly. You should have got some "inclomplete implementation" warning anyway.

Comment: :I am sorry,I am a beginner in native development Hermann.SUPConnectionProfile.h is the library file.It is not showing any incomplete implementation warning.Actually we used SUP 2.1.2 library files and generated code first.In that library file there were no methods like this.Anyways I know it is not reccomended ,but we used the library files from SUP 2.1.3 and the generated code of SUP 2.1.2.Because the library file contains the above mentioned methods.Then it is showing these error.I will attach the SUPConnectionProfile.h file